# How to write query when there is "read-only access" to the database ? What does it mean? eg. for each customer cal unq id for each day

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table contains the following columns:

```
timestamp, date, customer_id, page_id
```

For example, query is:

- for each customer, identify the first "`page_id`" that customer visited most recent day.

If there is a "read-only access" database. Are queries written differently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sql syntax doesn't depend on read/write priviliges. Run your query and see.

Comment: @Serg i thought i might have to add "grant" function before the query. I can simply write the query as we normally write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read-only access means you can only read and do query's that can read the database.

You won't be able to insert,update or drop tables.